# Jupyter notebook: image from github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

I've read [this](http://How%20to%20Include%20image%20or%20picture%20in%20jupyter%20notebook), but I'm still having issues.

I have an image (.png) saved on my GitHub account, and I want to show it in a Jupyter notebook markdown cell.

```
[IMAGE](https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/imagename.png)
```

doesn't work. It provides a link to the image instead of showing the image itself when the cell is run.

How can I show the image in the notebook instead of making the user click a link?

Comment: I never solved this problem - I just did without the image. I don't remember if it was a private repo, sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this

```
![PyTorch Logo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/docs/source/_static/img/pytorch-logo-dark.png)
```

Now, the question comes, how can we get this URL. So, for example, you want to get this image (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/docs/source/_static/img/pytorch-logo-dark.png). Goto GitHub, do right-click on this image and open it in the next tab. Copy the URL from the next tab and use it in the above-defined command.